# How to see whole session path in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm learning standard sql in BigQuery and I have a task, where I have to show, what users did after entering checkout - what specific urls they've visited. I figured out something like this, but it'll only show me one previous step and I have to see at least 5 of them. Is this possible? Thank you

```
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT hits.page.pagePath
      , LAG(hits.page.pagePath) OVER(ORDER BY i) prevPagePath
    FROM UNNEST(hits) hits WITH OFFSET i
  ) x
  FROM `xxxx.ga_sessions_20160801`
)
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, pagePath, prevPagePath
FROM path_and_prev, UNNEST(x) 
WHERE regexp_contains (pagePath,r'(checkout/cart)')
GROUP BY 2,3
ORDER BY
cnt desc
```

Comment: Use `lag()` five times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is official GA shema for BQ export : 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en
(Just a tip, feel free to export it in a sheet (Excel or Google or whatever) and indent decently to ease understanding of nesting :) )

The only way to safely get session behaviour is to get hits.hitNumber. Since pagePath is under page, which is under hits, hitnumber will always be specified :)

Up to you to filter on filled pagePath only, but still displaying hitnumber value.

Tell me if the solution does match your issue, or correct me :)

Comment: I don't really understand, sorry. Where should I put hitNumber?

Comment: "what users did after entering checkout", means every hit after checkout.
To get the "after", hitnumber works as an index.
Select hitnumber where pagePath is not null
Order by hitnumber
You will basically get your user session path(up to you to filter to get only 5 after it).

You did not mention it, but do not forget to work with the unique id ==> fullVisitorId + visitId.
Otherwise you'll mix data between users, i'm sure you are already using it, but just in case...